# Dropbox Datastore listDatastores on iOS

Tags: dropbox-api

I'm trying to write a method that will tell me if there are any datastores already available for my app. This is so I know what to do with some local data so I can add it to the datastore or skip it.

```
-(BOOL)isDatastorePresent
{
  DBAccount *account = [[DBAccountManager sharedManager] linkedAccount];
  DBDatastoreManager *dsm = [DBDatastoreManager managerForAccount:account];
  DBError *__autoreleasing *error = NULL;
  NSLog(@"Datastores: %@",[dsm listDatastores:error]); //-- Log: empty array
  NSLog(@"Error: %@",error); //-- Log: (null)

  NSLog(@"# datastores: %lu",(unsigned long)[[dsm listDatastores:nil] count]); 
  //-- Log: 0
}
```

I know I have a datastore for my app already, but this **always yields 0 datastores**. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue here is that the SDK hasn't finished downloading the information about the available datastores before you call `listDatastores`.

You'll want to wait for this information to be available before getting this list. You can do this by registering an observer on the DBDatastoreManager to be notified of changes:

[https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/docs/ios#DBDatastoreManager.addObserver:block:](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/docs/ios#DBDatastoreManager.addObserver%3ablock%3a)

**EDIT from smarx**:

Adding code per Greg's suggestion in the comments.

```
DBObserver dsmBlock = ^() {
  NSLog(@"Datastores: %@",[dsm listDatastores:error]);
  NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
  NSLog(@"#datastores: %lu",(unsigned long)[[dsm listDatastores:nil] count]);    
}
[dsm addObserver:self block:dsmBlock];
[dsmBlock invoke];
```

Comment: Hmm... that could be it. I just tried it (code: http://d.pr/n/beht) but the block never fires.

Comment: The block will only get called when things change, so it's possible you're actually missing it while adding the observer. To be sure, you should do addObserver, but that call it once manually after that to check if you did hit that race condition.

Comment: Okay... well, my basic goal here is to just find out if the user already has a datastore for my app. Do you think using listDatastores is the right way to go about this?

Comment: Thanks, Smarx. Xcode is complaining about the `[dsm addObserver:self dsmBlock];` line saying `Expected ':'`

Comment: Regarding the best practice, it really depends on what you're trying to do. For example, if you're using the default datastore, you can just open it. If you're looking for datastores created by other clients using createDatastore, then yes, listDatastores will be needed

Comment: Yes, I want to know if other clients have already created a datastore.

Comment: @CliftonLabrum I just fixed the code sample, sorry.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry to drag this on further, but the observer block fires, but it still yields 0 datastores. I know I'm connected because my `DBAccount` object has data in it. Right after the block fires, I get: `[WARNING] ERR: DROPBOX_ERROR_SHUTDOWN: DBHTTPRequest.mm:572: Request cancelled.`

Comment: It's possible your dsm is going out of scope, in which case you won't get the expected information back. So, make sure you retain that, on way or another. If it goes out of scope the observer will get dropped.

Comment: Sorry to bring this back up again, but I still can't get consistent results out of `listDatastores`. I can do every other API operation in the same context, but trying to get the datastores yields `nil`. I can access tables within the datastore, but I can't list the datastores themselves. Anyone else having issues with that method? Will only having the default datastore yield none?

Comment: I just saw your answer from 5/15. Using the observer is recommended though and you may see inconsistent results if you don't use it. For the current inconsistencies you're seeing, are you using the observer? Do you have any logging you could share to illustrate the behavior you're seeing? I don't believe having only the default datastore should yield none.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound strange, but adding the observer turned out to not be necessary. I just pulled the datastore list as shown in my question.

The issue seemed to be that the Datastore API got "stuck" somehow. I started doing some other sync operations to see if the Datastore browser was responding, and nothing was happening. After logging out of my Dropbox account (on the web) and back in again, the syncs started occurring and the datastore list started populating out of the blue.