# Dropbox on Android - listDatastores is not syncing

Tags: android, dropbox-api

After linking my Dropbox account, I try to gather and store the datastore names inside of my local database. All is fine when I'm debugging my app, I can find all names inside of the datastore as well. But when I'm running the app without debugging, my database seems empty.

I think there is a problem of syncing, somebody could give me clue? I haven't found out solution corresponding to my issue.

Thank you if you can help me!

This is the part of the code in question:

```
private void gatherData(){

        db = new SQliteHelper( this ) ;
        Set<DbxDatastoreInfo> datastorePresent = null ;



        try {
            datastorePresent = mDatastoreManager.listDatastores();
        } catch (DbxException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Iterator<DbxDatastoreInfo> datastoreLoop = datastorePresent.iterator() ;
        while (datastoreLoop.hasNext()){

            TitleList tit = new TitleList(datastoreLoop.next().id) ;
            tit.setConnectDropbox();
            db.addLists(tit);

        }

        mDatastoreManager.shutDown();

          Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
          boolean syncOK = true ;
          returnIntent.putExtra("result", syncOK) ;
          setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
          finish();


    }
```

Comment: This is likely the same as or similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664650/dropbox-datastore-listdatastores-on-ios In short, you may be calling listDatastores before the SDK knows about the datastores, so use a listener on your DBDatastoreManager.

Comment: @Greg thanks for your help! Indeed, I had seen this post but I don't know how to address the listener on Android. Could you give me an example?

Comment: The tutorial here shows how to add a listener to a DbxDatastoreManager: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/tutorial/android#listeners

Answer (score 0):

As @Greg told me on Dropbox website there is a [tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/tutorial/android#listeners) to display a listener. As it could be usefull for some others, below you will find the code I have finally used. Be aware you do have implemented the interface **DbxDatastoreManager.ListListener** by your class in order to make this code runnable.

Code:

```
private void gatherData(){

        /**
         * Open the local database
         * Set a listener on the datastore manager to know when data are synced
         * 
         */
        db = new SQliteHelper( this ) ;
        mDatastoreManager.addListListener(this);

    }


    /**
     * 
     * "onDatastoreListChange" is launched once the listener detects datastore is synced,
     * Then all datastore names on dropbox server are stored inside of the local database device
     * 
     * @param arg0
     */
    @Override
    public void onDatastoreListChange(DbxDatastoreManager arg0) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Set<DbxDatastoreInfo> datastorePresent = null ;
        try {
            datastorePresent = mDatastoreManager.listDatastores();
        } catch (DbxException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        Iterator<DbxDatastoreInfo> datastoreLoop = datastorePresent.iterator() ;
        while (datastoreLoop.hasNext()){

            TitleList tit = new TitleList(datastoreLoop.next().id) ;
            tit.setConnectDropbox();
            db.addLists(tit);

        }

          Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
          boolean syncOK = true ;
          returnIntent.putExtra("result", syncOK) ;
          setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
          finish();

    }
```